# Why won't my image display?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Do y'all see anything wrong with my code below?  I want my image to appear immediately after page opens but it only opens after the report is run.  If this looks complete then could javascript help? Please let me know.  Thanks.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SelectionReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="Geocortex.Essentials.WebFramework.SelectionReportPage" Culture="auto" UICulture="auto" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title><asp:Literal meta:resourcekey="Title1" runat="server" /></title>        
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <p>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageAlign="Left" 
                ImageUrl="~/Images/Loading.gif" 
                style="z-index: 1; left: 254px; top: 15px; position: absolute" />
        </p>
        <gcx:SelectionReportViewer ID="SelectionReportViewer" runat="server" />

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm still not having any luck with this.  I can get the image to show up when the SelectionReportViewer is removed from the form but obviously I need that control to create the report.  Does anyone have any bright ideas on how I can get the image to show up before the SelectionReportViewer gets involved?  That control does have some events: Databinding, disposed, init, load, prerender,unload

Comment: Can someone please help me with this issue?  Through further testing, this is where I am so far:  My ASPX page contains a form1 which has Image1 and a ReportViewer control.  But before the ASPX gets loaded the SelectionReport.cs runs through a lengthy process of creating the report and it is HERE I need to generate a Loading.gif before the report is being generated.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is really jumping out at me, but have you tried increasing the z-index?  Maybe the ReportViewer is just showing over top of it?

Comment: I tried setting the z-index to 500 and the image still won't show up until after the report is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your report control is trying to generate the report during the initial page load.  You want to load the page without the report, and then use Javascript to initiate the report load, preferably through some AJAX technique so you don't have to postback the page.  I'm not familiar with that control so I'm not sure if there is a way to make it not generate the report on the initial load, or if you need to add the control itself dynamically.